# SPARQL wikidata get state/province of all cities of a particular country

Tags: timeout, sparql, wikidata

I am trying to get all cities and their states/province of a country. Here I got all cities of Canada successfully using this below query.

[**Cities Wikidata SPARQL**](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fcity%20%3FcityLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fcity%20wdt%3AP17%20wd%3AQ16%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%28wdt%3AP31%2F%28wdt%3AP279%2A%29%29%20wd%3AQ515%3B%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%7D%0AORDER%20BY%20%3FcityLabel) -- It works

```
SELECT ?city ?cityLabel WHERE {
  ?city wdt:P17 wd:Q16;
    (wdt:P31/(wdt:P279*)) wd:Q515;
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
ORDER BY ?cityLabel
```

I want to get the state/province of all cities. So, I tried this below query. But, it didn't work.

**[Cities & State/Province Wikidata SPARQL](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fcity%20%3FcityLabel%20%3FstateLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fcity%20wdt%3AP17%20wd%3AQ16%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%28wdt%3AP31%2F%28wdt%3AP279%2A%29%29%20wd%3AQ515%3B%0A%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP131%2A%20%3Fstate%20.%20%3Fstate%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ11828004%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%7D%0AORDER%20BY%20%3FcityLabel%0ALIMIT%205000)** -- Didn't work

```
SELECT ?city ?cityLabel ?stateLabel WHERE {
  ?city wdt:P17 wd:Q16;
    (wdt:P31/(wdt:P279*)) wd:Q515;
    wdt:P131* ?state . ?state wdt:P31 wd:Q11828004
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
ORDER BY ?cityLabel
LIMIT 5000
```

Comment: sometimes the query optimizer isn't smart enough. We can try to "help" and tell him that our order is the best for execution:`SELECT ?city ?cityLabel ?stateLabel WHERE {
  hint:Query hint:optimizer "None".
  ?city wdt:P17 wd:Q16;
    (wdt:P31/(wdt:P279*)) wd:Q515 .        
    ?city wdt:P131* ?state .?state wdt:P31 wd:Q11828004
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
ORDER BY ?cityLabel
LIMIT 5000`

Comment: @UninformedUser Thanks. It works. But, it returns too many duplicate city values.. :-(

Comment: well, of course it does - one row per matching in the dataset - that's the nature of SPARQL. Do `SELECT DISTINCT` in the beginning of your query. Anything beyond - i.e. multiple regions per city have to be aggregated via a function. But as far as I can see it's not necessary here, so just add `DISTINCT` and you're done

Comment: @UninformedUser Can you post this as answer? So, I can upvote & accept this as an answer.